# How can I get realtime Audio to Text conversion with a programming language?

Tags: python, windows, audio, text

I downloaded rainmeter in order to get some nifty computer stats showing while I work, and I found an audio visualizer that allows for you to see the frequency (I believe) at which noise is coming in around the office. This made me think, hmph, is it possible to get a realtime audio feed to translate to text with some sort of programming language? I figured this could be handy for any interviews I do and I wanted to reflect back on it, and it just seems like a cool concept to me. I do not want to download any third-party software, rather to take the time to learn some new coding concepts in either python, PowerShell, C, or anything. I am not limited to any language and it is up to the answerer's discretion!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) ? Seems interesting.

Comment: Very neat, thank you for the link! I am open to any idea, I would like to see where the project could go.